# Would a single section of 3 LED's from a LED strip still need the required 12V?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, led, battery

I have some LED strips which run off a 12V power brick, but what I don't know if that applies to even a single section which is only 3 LED's?

I was basically wondering if there was a way I could cut a single section of the LED strip and power it with a battery.

Comment: Yes it does, and yes you can.  The usual sources have the end clips that will break it out to wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cut an LED strip anywhere it says "cut here".

That section will happily run on 12V, as long as it's a 12V strip.

Comment: Could I use a smaller battery?

Comment: @mac_fan_33 It can use a small battery, but not one that is lower voltage  OR, go get some LEDs that use lower voltage (5V/6V are common), OR if you want to turn it into an electronics project, use a lower voltage battery with a boost converter to drive it up to 12V.

Comment: @mac_fan_33 You could use something like an [A23 battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A23_battery). Still 12V but small. Obviously, batteries that are physically smaller last a shorter time (if the chemistry is the same)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying to make my project as light and small as possible so I think getting a lower voltage LED might be my best bet.

Comment: If you want to stay in the ecosystem of the inespensive 12V strips - and you probably do... you are married either to 12V or a boost converter that makes 12V.   If you want to go lower voltage you'll need to go with (or hack) consumer products that do that (push lights etc.) or get into some custom electronics design.   A12V hardly needs to be a bulky lead-acid, 3-4 18650s or 10 AAA NiMH will suffice.